# How to remove files that are on iCloud

Tags: macos, icloud

I have files that are backed up on iCloud that I do not want on my local desktop (they are rather large video files that I rarely refer to). Is there a way to trigger iCloud to clean up space on my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a feature called optimise storage to store old and unused files on iCloud.

1. Click the Apple Logo in the top-left
2. Select About This Mac
3. Click on Storage in the System Information window
4. Click details

Then turn on **Store in iCloud**.

[image: example]

This uploads unused files to iCloud and deletes them from your Mac.

Alternatively, if you have a specific file you want to store on iCloud, go to [iCloud.com](https://www.icloud.com/) and upload the file/check if it is there then delete it off your Mac.